# Scale a set of probabilities so their sum is a target value

Tags: probability, normalization, logit, scales, linear-algebra

I have a set of probabilities; e.g.

$p = (0.95, 0.9, 0.6)$

I want to scale them up so that their sum moves from $\sum p = 2.45$ to $\sum p^* = 2.5$.

I think I need normalise to ensure the rescaled probabilities are not less than 1....

$\text{logit}(p) = \left(\log\left(\frac{0.95}{1-0.95}\right), \log\left(\frac{0.9}{1-0.9}\right), \log\left(\frac{0.6}{1-0.6}\right)\right) = (2.9444, 2.1972, 0.40545)$

then choose a scale value $\alpha$ to get the new $p^*$ that will satisfy my sum

$\text{logit}(p^*) = (2.9444\alpha, 2.1972\alpha, 0.40545\alpha)$

and get them back to probabilities using the inverse logit transformation.

$p^* = \left(\frac{\exp(2.9444\alpha)}{1+\exp(2.9444\alpha)}, \frac{\exp(2.1972\alpha)}{1+\exp(2.1972\alpha)}, \frac{\exp(0.40545\alpha)}{1+\exp(0.40545\alpha)} \right)$

I cannot figure out how to solve for $\alpha$ so that $\sum p^* = 2.5$...

$2.5 = \sum_i \frac{p_i\alpha}{1+p_i\alpha}$

From trial and error in in Excel I know $\alpha = 1.127545$ but I cannot seem to re-express the equation above to get a direct solution... my algebra is very shaky though, hence the bid for help?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to write the 'log' in your logit function...and what happens if the input values are 0 or 1? (the logit will blow up)

Comment: -thanks for the spot. in my applied setting I will not need to worry about 0 or 1 probabilities.

Comment: Why don't you just multiply them all by $2.5/2.45$? The lurking question is why would you do this? What do these probabilities represent and what is the scaling hoping to achieve?

Comment: @whuber It could be any number, say 5, then your approach won't work (as it will lead to probabilities greater than 1). I am trying to think of a way to scale up life expectancy from survivorships probabilities. There is bunch of other equations, but the crux of my problem boils down to problem here.

Comment: I'm intrigued, and I may be stuck in a similar problem. What is the sum of probabilities? What does that represent? Are you trying to arrive at a coefficient based on probabilities of survivorship, and you want that coefficient to be greater than 1?

Comment: @danno I am intrigued too. My guess is that these are age-specific probabilities and the sum is related to a summary measure such as life expectancy... in that case the sum must be less than or equal to 3 (if there are 3 age groups).